# Sumar un arreglo hasta n recursividad

Tags: java, recursión

Tengo este método que sirve para sumar un arreglo hasta N números, pero el problema es que yo quiero que me sume los primeros 4 números por ejemplo, pero me sumas los primeros 5 por el arreglo que inicia en 0. Adjunto mi código.

```
public int sumaArreglo(int arreglo[], int n) {
        if (n >= 0 ) {
            return  sumaArreglo(arreglo, n - 1)+ arreglo[n];
        }
        return 0;
    } // Fin de método
```

Por ejemplo, teniendo este arreglo de enteros `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` cuando llame al método `sumaArreglo(array, 3);` quiero que sume del 1 al 3. No del 1 al 4.

Comment: Hola, quiero entender tu pregunta, ¿quieres que no tome en cuenta el último elemento de tu arreglo o el primero?

Comment: ¿Y este return no te valdría en lugar del que tienes? `return sumaArreglo(arreglo, n - 1) + arreglo[n - 1];`

Comment: si agrego el n-1 me da un ArrayIndexOfBound @ArianJM

Comment: @chavalife17 quiero que no tome encuenta el último

Comment: si cambias esto: n >= 0 por esto n>0 no hace lo que queres?

Comment: @gbianchi no, porque en ese caso el número que se encuentra en el arreglo en la posición 0, no se sumaría.

Comment: si se suma.. cambia return 0 por return arreglo[0] ;)

Comment: y saca esto + arreglo[n].. igual, esto es mucho mas facil si vas de 0 a n que de la forma que lo estas haciendo.... porque tendrias que ir solamente hasta n-1

Comment: si lo hago así n > 0, sigue sumando desde el valor del 4to indice

Comment: En realidad ahora que lo miro bien, toda la logica es confusa.. porque queres ir de arriba para abajo?

Comment: y entonces cómo hago la suma desde 0 a n?

Comment: de esa forma se me ocurrió, porque si lo sumo el orden da igual

Comment: aparte que de esa forma logro usar e indicar el indice con el número del arreglo si tienes una mejor idea me ayudaría bastante, gracias. @gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tu problema está bien planteado, sólo que fallas en los índices del array. Esto es correcto si entendí bien tu problema, te comento los cambios:

```
 static int sumaArray(int array[], int n) {
    if (n >= 1) { //entra en el if n=3, n=2, n=1
        return sumaArray(array, n - 1)+array[n-1]; //suma la posición n-1, por lo que llegas a sumar las posiciones n=2, n=1, n=0
    }
    return 0;
 }
```

Pruébalo y verás que funciona. El código completo para probarlo es este:

```
public class ArrayN {
public static void main (String[] args){
    int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    System.out.println(sumaArray(array, 3));
}

static int sumaArray(int array[], int n) {
    if (n >= 1) {
        return sumaArray(array, n - 1)+array[n-1];
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Lo logré resolver, pero esto está muy bien también gracias, fuiste de mucha ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Toda la logica es confusa...

Si vos queres sumar los 3 primeros n, como el arreglo empieza en 0, entonces deberias sumar n-1 siempre...

Si quisieras ir para abajo, tal cual esta tu codigo, alcanza con que cambies la llamada:

```
sumaArreglo(arreglo, n-1);
```

Igual, eso complejiza el problema, porque si vas para arriba, se entiende mas facil lo que pasa...

```
public static int sumaArreglo(int arreglo[], int n, int pos) {
    if (pos == n) {
        return 0;
    }
    return sumaArreglo(arreglo, n, pos+1)+arreglo[pos];
}
```

Y lo llamas de la forma

```
sumaArreglo(arreglo, 3, 0);
```

Donde 3 es hasta donde queres sumar, y el 0 es siempre 0 porque es la posicion donde comenzas...

De esa forma, empieza sumando el primero, el segundo, el tercero, y cuando llega al 4 (que es la posicion 3) devuelve 0.

Comment: Bueno si serviría pero el que necesito solo tiene como parámetros el arreglo y el valor hasta el que quiero llega, no puedo usar otro más, como pos que me sirve de auxiliar para sumar hacia arriba

Comment: @carloszamora no entiendo. no podes usar otra funcion?es eso? tambien te respondi como arreglar la tuya, alcanza con que la llames diferente....

Comment: No es eso, me explico, tu estás usando pos, como entero de parámetro, pero mi método solo lleva por parametros el arreglo y el n

Comment: Te vuelvo a preguntar, no podes cambiar la funcion? que problema hay con eso? no entiendo el problema... @carloszamora.. igual te puse tambien como solucionar tu problema con tu funcion actual.. eso no lo entendiste?

Comment: ah ok, no había entendido, esa parte, pero, no entiendo como solucionar mi función, tu explicación no la entendí

Comment: No tenes que cambiar nada.. solo llamalo con un indice menos... @carloszamora.. si tenes mas dudas, me encontras en el [chat]